# Include Global Set Variable in Print Delimiters

Tags: templating, variable, environmentvariables

I have a site which has another group site - both use same templates but I want to include different phone number in the header of each.

I was wanting to use Global Set Variables to pull this information in.

It works fine in the execute delimiters but not in the print delimeters.

This works fine:

```
{% include "includes/#{ craft.config.siteCode }/head-constants" %}
```

Is there any way to include it within another variable like below:

```
{{ #{ craft.config.siteCode }Defaults.defaultTelephoneLink }}
```

This gives the Template Error: Unexpected character "#".

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to do something like this:

```
{{ "#" ~ craft.config.siteCode ~"Defaults.defaultTelephoneLink" }}
```

Comment: That outputs the string on the screen - not pull it from the database..

Comment: It's assuming you've got a custom `siteCode` config settings set in you `craft/config/general.php` file and it should concatenate the value of that config setting into the anchor.

Comment: Just realized you originally referenced a global set.  Any reason why you're going through `craft.config` for that?

Comment: I have 2 global sets with fixed info for each site, e.g tel no email, social links. So global sets are site1Defaults and site2Defaults. So I thought I could reference the same variable using the config settings for each site in general.php to change the global set being used. So just using the 1 template file. Can easily change it to include a different template file if need be.